# HTTPRequest syntax problem

Tags: bugs, syntax, web-access

**Bug introduced in V11.0 and persisting through 11.3**

> [CASE:3981157] confirmed

---

```
asso = <|
  "Scheme" -> "http"
, "Domain" -> "www.wolframalpha.com/"
, "ContentType" -> "application/json"
|>;
```

This is a valid and documented syntax:

```
HTTPRequest @ asso //InputForm
```

> ```
> HTTPRequest[
>   <|"Scheme" -> "http", "Domain" -> "www.wolframalpha.com/"|>
> , <|"ContentType" -> "application/json"|>
> ]
> ```

but it breaks when one provides options:

```
HTTPRequest[asso, CharacterEncoding -> Automatic] // InputForm
```

> ```
> HTTPRequest[
>   <|"Scheme" -> "http", "Domain" -> "www.wolframalpha.com/", "ContentType" -> "application/json"|>
> , <||>
> , CharacterEncoding -> Automatic
> ]
> ```

So it was not split correctly on url and metadata part. Which will result in malformed request.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So before it is fixed one needs to arrange full input with help of e.g. `URLBuild`:

```
HTTPRequest[
  URLBuild@asso, asso, CharacterEncoding -> Automatic
] // InputForm
```

> ```
> HTTPRequest[
>   "http://www.wolframalpha.com//"
> , <|..., "ContentType" -> "application/json"|>
> , CharacterEncoding -> Automatic
> ]
> ```